# How to include a custom menu in page.tpl

Tags: routes, theming

I want to code a custom menu straight into page.tpl.php. The default theme uses

```
<?php if ($main_menu): ?>
  <div id="main-menu" class="navigation">
    <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
      'links' => $main_menu,
      'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'main-menu-links',
        'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
      ),
      'heading' => array(
        'text' => t('Main menu'),
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
      ),
    )); ?>
  </div> <!-- /#main-menu -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

In Drupal 7 I've created a new menu called 'Footer menu'. How do I code that into my theme in the same way as the $main_menu is coded  in the default theme?

Comment: Your custom menu will be available as a block, you can simply place that into footer region. This will save you some time and effort.

Comment: I understand that, however I want to have more control over the output like I would have in the example above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
 $menu = menu_navigation_links('menu-your-custom-menu-name');
 print theme('links__menu_your_custom_menu_name', array('links' => $menu));
?>
```

You can also add to template.php

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

$menu = menu_navigation_links('menu-your-custom-menu-name');

$vars['custom_menu'] = theme('links__menu_your_custom_menu_name', array('links' => $menu));

}
```

the variable $custom_menu is available in the page tpl

Comment: I understand that this goes into template.php, but how do I reference the menu in the page template?

Comment: you can use this code directly in tpl.

Answer (score 0):

you can override your menu with `hook_theme_tree()` in `template.php`:

```
function THEME_menu_tree__MENUNAME($variables) {
  $menuTree = menu_build_tree('MENUNAME');

  foreach ($menuTree as $item) {

  }
}
```

and then create MENU BLOCK Or just print your menu directly in your `page.tpl`

Answer (score 0):

Well, Nothing from above worked for me with Drupal 7 but below code,

```
    $search_menu_name = "menu-search-box-menu";

   print theme('links', array('links' => menu_navigation_links($search_menu_name), 'attributes' => array('id' => $search_menu_name, 'class'=> array('links', 'inline'))));
```

The above code is like this, "menu-search-box-menu" is my custom menu name/ID. You can find it in that particular menu edit link.

Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using bellow code,It's working for me.

$main_menu = menu_navigation_links('menu-main-page');
print($main_menu);

Answer (score 0):

This has been driving me mad.

The easiest way by far is this...

In page.tpl.php where your custom menu name is "Custom Menu"

```
<?php

print drupal_render(menu_tree('menu-custom-menu'));

?>
```